# What are the pros and cons of using the Hadoop NameNode, Checkpoint Node and Backup Node?

Tags: hadoop

I'm currently evaluating Hadoop 1.0.2 for an in-house project.

The Hadoop docs say that

> [The Secondary NameNode has been deprecated. Instead, consider using the Checkpoint Node or Backup Node](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/hdfs_user_guide.html#Secondary+NameNode)

There is information on what the three options *are* and what they *do*, but I'm having trouble finding information on which of the three options is *recommended* in which situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the checkpoint node is a new implementation of the secondary name node and the backup point is an interim release on the way to a warm-standby for the namenode (plus it can currently offer a small performance boost by separating reads and writes - reads in the name node and writes in the backup node

from the [Backupnode documentation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4539) as explained by Konstantin Shvachko :

> This patch introduces two new types of name-nodes: a Checkpoint node and a Backup node.
>
> - The role of the Checkpoint node to checkpoint name-node meta-data by
>     merging image and edits files.
> - The Backup node extends functionality
>     of the Checkpointer by that it can receive online updates of the file
>     system meta-data, apply them to its memory state and persist them on
>     disks just like the name-node does. Thus at any time the Backup node
>     contains an up-to-date image of the namespace both in memory and on
>     local disk(s). This also results in much more efficient checkpointing
>     because backup node does not need to transfer files from the active
>     name-node and does not need to replay (merge) edits.
> - The Term Standby node
>     is reserved for further extension of the backup node functionality,
>     when cluster will be able to switch over to the new name-node if the
>     active dies. This is mentioned in the "Warm standby provision" section
>     of the design document.
>
> Typical use cases:
>
> 1. Run Checkpoint node only to create checkpoints. This should be used
>      instead of the current SecondaryNameNode, which is deprecated by the
>      patch. I reused a lot of the SecondaryNameNode code so this effort was
>      not wasted, it just evolved.
> 2. Run Backup node to support online
>      streaming of edits and efficient checkpointing. This particularly
>      targets eliminating NFS as a remote storage for edits.
> 3. Run NameNode
>      without persistent storage at all and delegate all "persisting"
>      functionality to the Backup node. The trick here is to start name-node
>      with -importCheckpoint option and then run the Backup node.