# Difference between secondary name node and standby name node in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I couldn't understand the difference between secondary name node and standby name node and backup name node. I am looking for in depth understanding of these terms. Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424718/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-the-hadoop-namenode-checkpoint-node-and-bac/10424902#10424902

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the pros and cons of using the Hadoop NameNode, Checkpoint Node and Backup Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424718/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-the-hadoop-namenode-checkpoint-node-and-bac)

Answer (score 15):

Secondary namenode is just a helper for Namenode.

It gets the edit logs from the namenode in regular intervals and applies to fsimage.

Once it has new fsimage, it copies back to namenode.

Namenode will use this fsimage for the next restart, which will reduce the startup time.

Secondary Namenode's whole purpose is to have a checkpoint in HDFS. Its just a helper node for namenode. That’s why it also known as checkpoint node.

But, It cant replace namenode on namenode's failure.

So, Namenode still is Single-Point-of-Failure.

To overcome this issue; `STANDBY-NAMENODE` comes into picture.

It does three things:

1. merging fsimage and edits-log files. (Secondary-namenode's work)
2. receive online updates of the file system meta-data, apply them to its memory state and persist them on disks just like the name-node does.

   ```
   Thus at any time the Backup node contains an up-to-date image of the namespace both in memory and on local disk(s).
   ```
3. Cluster will switch over to the new name-node (this standby-node) if the active namenode dies.

Comment: Is secondary name node same as checkpoint name node ? What is backup namenode?

Comment: Yes, Secondary name node is Checkpoint name node - which only merges fsimage and edit logs in an interval.

Backup namenode is extension to Secondary namenode - that additionaly, receives updates on real time of fs metadata from namenode - making sure that on-memory and on-disk image is up-to-date.

Stand-by namenode is extension to backup namenode - that can become active/real namenode at any given time when real namenode dies.

Answer (score 5):

However, the answer explained above is satisfactory but I want to add some points to it.
About **Standby-Namenode**
Both active and standby Namenode use a ***shared directory*** and standby Namenode sync through that directory from time to time so there must be no delay in activating it if the active Namenode goes down.
But the main factor is about the block reports, Block reports are not written in edit-logs, they are stored in local disk space. So syncing with a shared directory is not enough.
To avoid this conflict, data-nodes has the addresses of both the name-nodes,
and they send the block reports to both of them but they only follow the block commands coming from the active Namenode.

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 3):

Standby Node : In the case of an unplanned event such as a machine crash, the cluster would be unavailable until an operator restarted the NameNode.Planned maintenance events such as software or hardware upgrades on the NameNode machine could result in whole cluster downtime. So a Standby Node comes in action which is nothing but a backup for the Name Node .

Secondary NameNode : It is one of the poorest named part of the hadoop ecosystem usually beginners get confused thinking of it as a backup.Secondary NameNode in hadoop is a specially dedicated node in HDFS cluster whose main function is to take checkpoints of the file system metadata present on namenode. It is not a backup namenode. It just checkpoints namenode’s file system namespace. The Secondary NameNode is a helper to the primary NameNode but not replace for primary namenode.

Answer (score 0):

The Secondary namenode maps the fsimage and the edit log transactions periodically stores them in a shared storage location in case of HA enabled HDFS Cluster.

In other hand, Standby node has the ability to transfer the latest built fsimage to the Active NameNode via HTTP Get call .

So the main difference between Secondary and standby namenode is secondary namenode does not upload the merged Fsimage with editlogs to active namenode
where as the standby node uplods the merged new image back to active Namenode.
So the NameNode need to fetch the state from the Secondary NameNode